# Bloom Filter False Positives

Tags: c++, bloom-filter

I am implementing a BloomFilter and have to calculate the number of false positives by adding [0,N] elements and then checking to see if the filter contains (n,oo) elements. I am having issues calculating the correct number of false positives. In my loop every time possiblycontains() tells me that my filter contains an element in (n,oo) I add to the false positives.
But for example when I have a filter of 16 elements I get 10 false positives and the rate of false positives as 0.

Any help would be appreciated

```
for (int numNotInFilter =size+1; numNotInFilter<2*size; numNotInFilter++)
{
                if (myBloom.possiblyContains((const uint8_t*)(&numNotInFilter), sizeof(int)))
        {
            numOfFalsePositives+=1.0;
        }
}
    double RateOfFalsePositives = (numOfFalsePositives) / ((2 * size) - 1);
```

Comment: Did you expect `RateOfFalsePositives` to be between 0 and 1?  It's an integer type.

Comment: Ok I fixed that. Is my loop correct?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this library in the past when dealing with [bloom filters](https://github.com/ArashPartow/bloom) There is an example where encountered false positives are calculated:

https://github.com/ArashPartow/bloom/blob/master/bloom_filter_example02.cpp

From what I can tell of whats happening in the example, the rate of false positive probability is not only based on the number of false positives encountered but is also a function of the bloom filter size.